# Populating Events in to Tableview (Swift)

Tags: swift, tableview, eventkit

I am trying to populate my daily events in to tableview. I have made the connections. (datasource, delegate and tableview) But events value is returning 0. 
Sorry if this has been asked else where. I need a little help.

Here is my code.

import UIKit
import EventKit
import EventKitUI

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var eventStore: EKEventStore?
var events = [EKEvent]()
var startDate = NSDate()
var endDate = NSDate()
var cellIdentifier = "cell"


@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false


    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier);
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.eventStore = EKEventStore()

    fetchEvents { (arr:[EKEvent]) in
        print(arr)
        self.events = arr
        //reload table
    }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func fetchEvents(completed: ([EKEvent]) -> ()) {
    eventStore!.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        granted, error in
        let startDt = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -24 * 60 * 60);
        let predicate = self.eventStore!.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDt, endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)
        let events = self.eventStore!.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate)
        completed(events)
    })
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

@IBAction func onLoadListButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoadTheList", sender: nil)
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


//MARK: UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //TEST PRINT EVENT COUNT
    print("event count (print) \(events.count)")

    return events.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let events:EKEvent! = self.events[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = events.title
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = events.startDate.description
    print("event cell returned")
    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is your start date is `NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 24 * 60 * 60)` that is one day ahead and your end date is current date; in short, you are checking event starts tomorrow and ends today ;)

Just use following method to get events started yesterday and ends today. For further use just change the `startDt` to any previous date.

```
func fetchEvents(completed: (NSMutableArray) -> ()) {

    eventStore!.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        granted, error in
        let startDt = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -24 * 60 * 60);
        let predicate = self.eventStore!.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDt, endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)
        let events = NSMutableArray(array: self.eventStore!.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate))
        completed(events)
    })
}
```

**Edit**

Call this as:

```
    fetchEvents { (arr:NSMutableArray) in
            print(arr)
            //reload your table
        }
```

Comment: thank you! 

Can you say where should I use this function? in to viewdidload? Sorry I'm new in swift.

Comment: Yes, you can use this in viewDidLoad

Comment: Sorry for many questions. I used to call a function in viewdidload like this.

self.functionname() 

but now, I could not do this. self.fetchEvents()  "missing argument for parameter #1 in call" issue I ve got. 

I am trying this. 

self.fetchEvents(completed: (NSMutableArray) -> ()) {
        
        }

but it does not ok.:/

Comment: Thanks. but now, I am getting this error. 

function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)

Static string

Comment: Where is the exact error or on a specific line? Explain in detail so I can help.

Comment: I think its a breakpoint issue but I did not put a breakpoint. It's so strange.

http://imgur.com/a/nQGo1

http://imgur.com/a/MUb4i

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment:

> I think its a breakpoint issue but I did not put a breakpoint. It's so
>   strange. imgur.com/a/nQGo1 imgur.com/a/MUb4i – bourbon 2 mins ago

I had looked at your code, in that remove `viewWillAppear` method and add `self.eventStore = EKEventStore()` above the `fetchEvents` function call in viewDidLoad.

One more important point assign `arr` to `self.events` and then reload the table. I have just changed the return type of method use following:

Method:

```
func fetchEvents(completed: ([EKEvent]) -> ()) {
    eventStore!.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        granted, error in
        let startDt = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -24 * 60 * 60);
        let predicate = self.eventStore!.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDt, endDate: NSDate(), calendars: nil)
        let events = self.eventStore!.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate)
        completed(events)
    })
}
```

Method call:

```
 fetchEvents { (arr:[EKEvent]) in
        print(arr)
        self.events = arr
        //reload table
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. (without any issue)

But my tableview does not load events on my calendar. (I have an test  event for today.)

http://imgur.com/a/InvCs

Comment: Instead of '//reload table' add your table reload code

Comment: I dont get it. is it "self.tableview.reloadData()" or what kind of reload code here? 

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, just add that after 'self.events = arr'. Inside the fetchEvents completion.

Comment: If you think, my answers are correct, upvote it & accept as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! :) Oh I'm dying. Im so sorry. I ve added. But still getting 0 value of events. Events is returning 0. thats why?

I think because of enddate?

http://imgur.com/a/R5mIA

Comment: Do you have any idea? I controlled again, my connections about tableview IBOutlet, datasource and delegate. 

Still getting events value 0. What I am missing? I checked the class again and again.. :/